# passing arguments to another screen while using named routes

Tags: flutter, dart

so i'm making a basic bmi calculator app

this is bmiBrain.dart

```
class BmiBrain{



final int weight;
  final int height;

  double _bmi;

  BmiBrain({this.height, this.weight});

  String bmiCalculator(){
    _bmi = weight / pow(height, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getWeightStatus(){
    if(_bmi >= 25.0){
      return "OVERWEIGHT";
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5){
      return "NORMAL";
    } else {
      return "UNDERWEIGHT";
    }

  }

  String getDiagnostic(){
    if(_bmi >= 25.0){
      return "Your body height is too high";
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5){
      return "Your body weight is normal, Noice";
    } else {
      return "You are so poor you don't eat enough lol";
    }

  }
```

i defined a named route for my ResultPage

```
class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.grey,
        accentColor: Colors.indigo,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black12,
        textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => InputPage(),
        "/result": (context) => Result(),
      },
      initialRoute: "/" ,
    );
```

now this is how i'm trying to pass the data to the result screen

```
onPress: (){
          BmiBrain bmi = BmiBrain(height: height, weight: weight);
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/result", arguments: {
            "MyData": Result(bmi: bmi.bmiCalculator(), weightStatus: bmi.getWeightStatus(), diagnostic: bmi.getDiagnostic())
          });
```

this is where the data is supposed to go

```
children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Center(child: Text(
                      weightStatus.toUpperCase(),
                      style: weightStatusStyle,
                    )),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(child: Text(
                      bmi,
                      style: kHeavyFont.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 80.0
                      ),
                    )),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
                    child: Center(

                        child: Text(
                      diagnostic,
                      style: kLabelText,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                  )
                ],
```

i previously got "null tried to call >=25.5" as error,  so i changed the order in which i was passing my arguments but it just caused another error: "null tried to call toUppercase", so i guess the problem comes from my code but i don't where is it hiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calculating the BMI, you should make sure that the weight and height values are not null. the previous error's cause was that the _bmi was null so it was trying to compare null with a number like this: null >= 25.5 and that is wrong. for preventing this to happen you should either initialize weight and height with values like this:

```
final int weight = 1;
final int height = 1;
```

or make sure that the values are not null in the calculating function like this:

```
  String bmiCalculator(){
if (weight != null && height != null) {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
}
else return -1;
  }
```